# Julia plots consistently not working

Tags: julia

I have been trying to plot using the "Plots" package in Julia and it never seems to plot anything. Specifically, I am using a Jupyter notebook with a Julia kernel, and every time I try to plot something the output is blank. This is really frustrating especially when I try using the code (below) provided in the Plots tutorial and it doesn't even work. I installed and updated the Plots package and nothing comes out. No errors or anything just a blank cell.

```
using Plots
x = 1:10 ; y = rand(10) # These are the plotting data
plot(x,y)
```

Why isn't this working?

Comment: You should include info on which backend you are using, as some will play nicer with Jupyter than others. Also, if possible, check whether your current backend works at the REPL, which will make it easier to isolate whether the problem is specific to Jupyter, or is more systemic to that particular backend.

Comment: Or open an issue on Plots. There's nothing wrong with your code, and the error you report is very unusual.

Comment: Specifically, can you note which backend you use, the version of the backends and Plots, your OS version and your web browser? Using Plots in Jupyter depends on many different components playing together - the error is likely to not be in Plots itself.

Comment: I got it to work, but I don't know what I did, lol. I was using latest version of Chrome browser and windows 10. I was attempting to use Plotly, and plots.jl.

Answer (score 1):

```
using Plots
x = 1:10 ; y = rand(10) # These are the plotting data
gr()
plot(x,y)
```

It is good practice to mention the backend plotting engine, in this case, GR.

Also, when you are working with Julia, the packages are dynamically loaded. So, when you are using a package, it may take some significant amount of time.

Also, a tip. When you see a star before the cell in Jupyter, like `In[*]`, please understand that the cell is still being executed.

Reference: [Julia Tutorial](https://www.tutorialkart.com/julia/) - [Julia Plots](https://www.tutorialkart.com/julia/julia-plots/)